# How to make a custom function made in Google Apps Script reactive to changes in the background of a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function that returns the hex code of the background color of the pointed cell. Its ok so far but I need this to be reactive to changes in the background color of the pointed cell. As it is, every time the background color of the cell changes I have to call again the function in order to it takes notice of that the background color has changed. There is any way to make this function reactive to changes in the background of thhe pointed cell?

```
  function color(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var address = formula.substr(7,2);

  var cell = ss.getRange(address); 
  var result = cell.getBackground(); 
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You should use onEdit or onChange events to capture such changes.

Comment: I don't think changes in background trigger onEdit or onChange triggers

Comment: @Ismail i didnt try onEdit or onChange yet, i guess it should recognize changes in the background but i am afraid that it can be too greedy and trigger the function on any change or edit  made in the spreadsheet and not only because of changes in the background color.

Comment: The event (e) gives you information about which cell or range was changed. It also gives you info about changed value and previous value.

Comment: e.range  would give you information about which cell, you can then check if the cell is what you need to check. If that is true, then you can check value or format changes accordingly.

Comment: You need to explicitly set an OnChange trigger from triggers options to make this work for you.

Comment: Thx @Ismail I have been looking OnChange(e) but "range" is not part of the event object it creates.

Comment: @jgjuara In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample spreadsheet? In particular I'm interested in `input` and data retrieved `var address = formula.substr(7,2)`

Answer (score 1):

onEdit() is not triggered by background changes but as it turns out onChange is and the changeType is FORMAT

Here's a copy of the event object:

```
{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"FORMAT","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```

[onChange event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

But I don't think that there is a way to take advantage of this with a custom function if what you mean by custom function is found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Try this:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  if(e.changeType == 'FORMAT') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());
  }
}
```

Comment: thx! This could work but I would need to check also the range, and it seems not to be part of that event object. Maybe combining triggers could find a workaround? Otherwise I will make the users edit the cell when they change the format and use the OnEdit(e) trigger as @Ismail suggested in a comment

Comment: The range is not part of the event object

Comment: Forcing the users to edit may not be necessary.  Perhaps you can just get the current active range.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
function onChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  console.log(ss.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation() + " onchange" );
}
```

This log will be available to you in trigger executions logs section.